# improve efficiency of graph() function reading txt file in python using networkx library

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I have a txt file with 150,000 lines, each with a number identifier (i.e. 1,2,3...)

Each line has some relation to another line, meaning the identifier of that line is either mentioned in other lines, or mentions other lines within it.

For example

```
#1 - string #24 #11
#11 - string #24 #25
#245 - string #1 #11
```

So in this case line 1 and and 11 are mentioned in line 245, but line 1 also mentions line 11 etc.

I am mapping the entire txt file using `import networkx as nx` and the function
 `G=nx.Graph()`, in order to later on manipulate relationships between different nodes and edges.

I am trying to understand how to make this more efficient, the runtime is currently very long (hour+) and I'm trying to understand if this function is the cause of the lengthy runtime:

```
 G=nx.Graph()
  for l in txt:
    res = re.findall("#\d{3,10}",l)
    if len(res) > 1:
      for num in res[1:]:
        G.add_edge(res[0],num)
  return G
```

Is there a way to either make it more efficient?

Comment: "since I suspect that running this function on 150,000 lines is a very lengthy operation" Test it. You haven't tagged the question with the specific library you use.

Comment: Thanks roganjosh, I've edited my post to fit your comment

Comment: The code you've shown appears to be about as efficient as it's possible to be for the task you have at hand. Perhaps you should profile your code to make sure that building the graph is the slow part.

Comment: Thanks blckknight, can you explain what you mean by 'profile my code'?
I am also performing 

`for child in children:
        grandchildren = list( Digraph.successors(child) )`

SEVERAL times in order to get more and more information from the tree. Is there any quicker way to do it other than scan the tree multiple times?

Comment: one tiny thing, you can probably remove `if len(res)>1:`.  the loop `for num in res[1:]:` will just do nothing if `res` has length 1 or 0.  This tiny change probably won't make much difference.

Comment: How long does it take to run this?  And how long do the other operations you're doing with this graph take to run in comparison?

Comment: Thanks Joel, I don't know how long it takes to run each of the operations, I just know that the whole script takes well more than an hour...

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky: I'd start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), though profiling is too big of a topic to really be explained in a comment.

Comment: Thank you Blckknght!
Also Thanks Joel for the short line improvement, might help. I also think that I ran the graph function twice where I shouldn't have so I just saved 50% ;)